# PVC hole repair in tight space

Tags: leak, pvc, hole-repair

I have a PVC pipe inside the wall in the right front corner of my office closet.  It has holes in it, and it carries washing machine water from washing machine to the basement to dispose of it however it does.  The holes are causing water to leak every time I do laundry.

I purchased a pipe repair wrapping kit, and was just about to repair, when I realized that behind the pipe is a another wall and there isn't enough space to bring the wrap around behind the PVC.

So as far as I can tell, I have two options:

1. Go and buy a Fernco and connect them that way (I may yet have the same problem-I'm not sure the Fernco would fit either)
2. Cut into the wall behind the pipe and make a square so I have room to wrap.

I don't like 2 because I don't know what's behind the back wall, and I think it will be difficult to repair the drywall.

Here's a picture (the holes in the pipe are there because I'm a moron):

[image: Image of pipe and rear wall]

I could use some guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to repair a damaged PVC pipe is of course to cleanly cut away the damaged portion and use a coupler. But, because this is a drain pipe and thus isn't pressurized, you could probably get away with just using epoxy to repair the holes.

Buy a PVC-suitable epoxy that's listed for use with water (e.g., J-B Weld makes a product called Waterweld), follow the directions, and liberally apply it to plug the holes. Clean off all the burrs from the holes first, to ensure a good bond. Make sure to give it plenty of time to dry before using your washing machine.

Comment: The kit included `Rectorseal EP 200 Epoxy Putty`.  Would that be sufficient?  Also, do you know what the dry time is approx?  Thanks

Comment: That should work; the specs say it's suitable for plumbing repairs. Just make sure to follow the instructions carefully -- epoxy putty needs to be kneaded thoroughly before you can apply it. The cure time is 30 minutes, but I would suggest waiting 24 hours to ensure it's fully dried (you can test the outside portion with your fingers, but the portion inside the pipe will probably take longer to dry).